# process.OutputDataReceived not read all lines

Tags: c#

result from cmd

```
C:\Users\XXXXX>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now *
* daemon started successfully *

C:\Users\XXXXX>
```

my c# code.

```
public string devicesPlus()
{
    psi.Arguments = "start-server";
    call = Process.Start(psi);
    call.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(call_OutputDataReceived);
    call.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(call_OutputDataReceived);
    call.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    call.Exited += new EventHandler(call_Exited);
    call.Start();
    call.BeginOutputReadLine();
    call.BeginErrorReadLine();
    call.StandardInput.Close();
    call.WaitForExit();
    return outData.ToString();
}

private void call_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        outData.Append(e.Data);
    }
}
```

Now when i call devicesPlus,some time i get only * daemon not running. starting it now *
some time it's just working in background and no result..
can you guys tell me whats wrong in my code,why i don't get correct return like cmd..
new to c# sorry for bad english...

**Update**
if i kill adb from outside my app i get reply from my software suddenly.

Comment: The code cannot work as posted, the UseShellExecute property assignment is missing.  Not using CreateNoWindow and not redirecting input is risky.  Clearly you can't get an accurate answer when you don't post accurate code.

Comment: i know about it sir,psi is part of abstract class..

Answer (score 5):

`WaitForExit()` only waits for the process to exit. It does not wait for your process to receive all output, so you have a race condition there.

`call_OutputDataReceived` will get called with `e.Data == null` to signify the end of the output. You need to wait for that call before using `outData.ToString()`.

For example, you could use a `new CountdownEvent(2)` to wait for the end of the two streams:

```
    CountdownEvent countdownEvent;
    
    public string devicesPlus()
    {
        psi.Arguments = "start-server";
        countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(2);
        call = Process.Start(psi);
        call.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(call_OutputDataReceived);
        call.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(call_OutputDataReceived);
        call.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        call.Exited += new EventHandler(call_Exited);
        call.Start();
        call.BeginOutputReadLine();
        call.BeginErrorReadLine();
        call.StandardInput.Close();
        call.WaitForExit();
        countdownEvent.Wait();
        return outData.ToString();
    }

    private void call_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            // prevent race condition when data is received form stdout and stderr at the same time
            lock (outData)
            {
                outData.Append(e.Data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // end of stream
            countdownEvent.Signal();
        }
    }
```

Comment: dear sir thank you for reply,i try with but nothing happen,if i kill the adb from outside my c# app,i get reply suddenly,and i fail to fix it..

Comment: Thx for code, but need using countdownEvent.Signal(); for decrease count not countdownEvent.AddCount(); - 

countdownEvent.Wait(); work when countdown is 0

Comment: @Geograph Thanks, I've changed AddCount() to Signal()

Answer (score 3):

add these lines to also read the [StandardError stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx):

```
psi.Arguments = "start-server";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

call = Process.Start(psi);
call.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(call_OutputDataReceived);
call.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(call_OutputDataReceived);
call.Exited += new EventHandler(call_Exited);

call.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

call.BeginOutputReadLine();
call.BeginErrorReadLine();
call.StandardInput.Close();

call.WaitForExit();

return outData.ToString();
```

Comment: same sir nothing happen with this..

Comment: I've added a few settings on the ProcessStartInfo, removed the extra call to Start.. give this a try...

Comment: i update post plz help sir..